# Replace a character from a string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, character

I use `Readline()` to read a string from a serial port.

But the problem is the string is always appended with `"\r"` at the end.

I have tried

```
text.Replace("\r","");
```

But it is not working.

Any other alternatives ?

Comment: Does the value actually have the text "\r" in it, or does it have carriage returns in it?

Comment: Strings are immutable, you cannot update them once they have been constructed, only create new copies. `Replace` is a function that will return a new string as the current string cannot be updated.

Comment: Use `serialPort1.NewLine = "\r\n";`  The default is \n so leaves the \r in the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Replace` doesn't work in-place. you have to assign the result to a variable.

```
text = text.Replace("\r","");
```

or simply

```
text = text.Trim();
```

Comment: And also use a double slash "\\r"

Comment: @CodingWithSpike absolutely no. "\\r" is not `Carriage return`

Comment: d'oh, your right, i'm an idiot. I read it in someone else's answer and thought they were right. thats what I get for being on SO too early in the morning before my coffee.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the result to some string to get the string without `\r`

Change

```
 text.Replace("\r","");
```

To

```
text = text.Replace("\r","");
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but it can be related with copying the I4V's answer.

Comment: I did not and I think I am the first to tell to assign back to text.

Comment: I did not copied, I executed my code in linqpad and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

escape `\` by doubling it,

```
text.Replace("\\r","");
```

or use `@`, verbatim string

```
text.Replace(@"\r","");
```

Comment: @Ajay then are you sure that you are exactly replacing `\r`?

Comment: @Ajay try `text.Replace(@"\r\n","");`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `@` [`verbtaim literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) like;

```
text.Replace(@"\r","");
```

or you can use double slah (`\\`)

```
text.Replace("\\r","");
```

`\r` is **Carriage return** character literal. Check out [`Character literals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

And just be careful about [`String.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method because it has two overloads.

- [`Replace(Char, Char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx)
- [`Replace(String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Comment: I guess some hatevoters here, but this is in my opinion the best answer(regarding the background information) +1

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead, as carriage return my vary depending on local culture:

```
text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

"...the string is always appended with "\r" at the end"

Then remove the last character:

```
string a = "hello\r";
string b = a.Substring(0, a.Length - 1);
```